# nonlinear ODE solution, is this correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the Ode $\frac{dy}{dx}=(y+4x)^2$
my attempt at a solution

let $u=y+4x$
$\implies du=dy$

so plugging back into the original EQ

$du/dx=u^2$

$du/u^2=dx$

integrating both sides gives

$-1/u +C=x+C$

$-1/u=x+C$

$-1/(x+C)=u$

$-1/(x+C)=y+4x$

$\implies y=-1/(x+C)-4x$

could any please tell me if this is the correct solution, and if its not any hints tips or tricks would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Tip: plug back your solution in the ODE to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

if you set $$u=y+4x$$ you will get $$u'=y'+4$$ and so you will have
$$u'-4=u^2$$

Answer (score 0):

If you plug in your solution

$$ y = -\frac{1}{x+c}-4x $$
$$ y' = \frac{1}{(x+c)^2}-4 $$
$$ (y+4x)^2 = \frac{1}{(x+c)^2} $$

So unfortunately it's incorrect. What you want instead is

$$ u = y+4x $$
$$ \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}+4 = u^2+4 $$

Solving this gives
$$ u(x) = 2\tan(2x+c)$$